# Upgrading to Solr 9 failes due to NoSuchFileException

Tags: solr

I want to install solr 9.x on a fresh linux server in order to run a pretty old application, migrating from solr 8.x. As of 9.x the data-import handler is no longer part of solr, therefore I installed https://github.com/SearchScale/dataimporthandler to overcome the issue.

Solr is running but the core will not load due to a config problem. I am unsure if it is related to dataimport-handler or any other issue.

Error log:

```
31/03/2024, 19:11:32
WARN false
findix
SolrConfig
Couldn't add files from /opt/solr-9.5.0/dist filtered by solr-dataimporthandler-.*\.jar to classpath: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /opt/solr-9.5.0/dist
31/03/2024, 19:11:32
ERROR false
findix
CoreContainer
SolrCore failed to load on startup
```

the file/folder dist does not exist, however /opt/solr-9.5.0/ does.

I suspect that the project on github does not support 9.5.0 but only 9.4.0
https://github.com/SearchScale/dataimporthandler/commit/2c8bee24f14888e1f12732ed4b84581ed2953366

While calling the application error msg:

```
Solr Error: org.apache.solr.core.SolrCoreInitializationException: SolrCore 'findix' is not available due to init failure: Could not load conf for core findix: Error loading solr config from /var/solr/data/findix/conf/solrconfig.xml at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:2280) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:2249) at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.init(HttpSolrCall.java:257) at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:509) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.dispatch(SolrDispatchFilter.java:262) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.lambda$doFilter$0(SolrDispatchFilter.java:219) at org.apache.solr.servlet.ServletUtils.traceHttpRequestExecution2(ServletUtils.java:249) at org.apache.solr.servlet.ServletUtils.rateLimitRequest(ServletUtils.java:215) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:213) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:195) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:210) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:527) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:131) at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:598) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:223) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1580) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:221) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1384) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:176) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:484) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1553) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:174) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1306) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:129) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:149) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.InetAccessHandler.handle(InetAccessHandler.java:228) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:141) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122) at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:301) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:822) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:563) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel$RequestDispatchable.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:1598) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:753) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:501) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:287) at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:314) at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:100) at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectableChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectableChannelEndPoint.java:53) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.runTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:421) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.consumeTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:390) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.tryProduce(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:277) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.run(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:199) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:411) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:969) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.doRunJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:1194) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1149) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core findix: Error loading solr config from /var/solr/data/findix/conf/solrconfig.xml at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSetService.loadConfigSet(ConfigSetService.java:278) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1707) at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$loadInternal$12(CoreContainer.java:1057) at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedRunnable.run(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:212) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:299) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ... 1 more Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error loading solr config from /var/solr/data/findix/conf/solrconfig.xml at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.readFromResourceLoader(SolrConfig.java:161) at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSetService.createSolrConfig(ConfigSetService.java:309) at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSetService.loadConfigSet(ConfigSetService.java:262) ... 9 more Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/usr/share/java" "read") at java.base/java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472) at java.base/java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:897) at java.base/java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:322) at java.base/java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:661) at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.checkRead(UnixPath.java:818) at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newDirectoryStream(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:399) at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newDirectoryStream(Files.java:604) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.getURLs(SolrResourceLoader.java:289) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.getFilteredURLs(SolrResourceLoader.java:318) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.initLibs(SolrConfig.java:969) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.(SolrConfig.java:243) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrConfig.readFromResourceLoader(SolrConfig.java:153) ... 11 more - also logged in/home/www/logs/solr-errors.log
q=*:*&start=0&rows=30&fq=type:classifieds&fq=country:DE&fq={!tag=white_label_id}white_label_id:0&fq=confirmed:1&fl=*,score&facet=true&facet.mincount=1&facet.limit=100&facet.field={!ex=province}province&facet.field={!ex=area}area&facet.field={!ex=quarter}quarter&facet.field={!ex=details}details&facet.field={!ex=rooms}rooms&facet.field={!ex=sqm}sqm&facet.field={!ex=picture}picture&facet.field={!ex=ad_type}ad_type&facet.field={!ex=xx_cat_1}xx_cat_1&facet.field={!ex=xx_cat_2}xx_cat_2&facet.field={!ex=xx_cat_3}xx_cat_3&stats=true&stats.field={!ex=price}price
```

What seems to be the problem here?